Install newest FFmpeg version on Ubuntu?
I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to get a non-depreciated version of FFmpeg on an Ubuntu installed.
(Side note: I'm using crostini)
I tried following FFmpeg's docs on getting all the things you need, then getting an install (which was a lot of tedious copy + paste, wait 5-6 minutes, just to have one of the libraries decide not to install because the directories were wrong or something?).
For some odd reason, FFmpeg has decided against updating the Linux repos, so they're stuck at 4.X, and the project I'm writing (I started on a different computer where it worked fine) complains that FFmpeg is too old.
Can anyone help me figure out how to:

Get and install FFmpeg (preferably 6.X or 7.X)
Set FFmpeg to PATH
figure out why FFmpeg decided not to update the Linux repos?


FFmpeg does not maintain the distro package repos - that's upto the distros. Get a GPL binary from https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/tag/latest

Maybe try to build from source? Takes less than 10 mins to build on an core i5 13600K.  If you are not a developer and is not familiar with the process, then you can try using some package management systems that pull from source and build for you with a few commands. I have tried vcpkg and I believe there are many like it.

bash script to dowload https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/download/latest/ffmpeg-master-latest-linux64-gpl.tar.xz
#!/bin/bash
#delete ~/.local/bin/ff* to download again
if [ ! -f ~/.local/bin/ffmpeg ]; then
  if [ ! -f /tmp/ffmpeg-master-latest-linux64-gpl.tar.xz ]; then
    wget -P /tmp/ https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/download/latest/ffmpeg-master-latest-linux64-gpl.tar.xz
  fi
  cd /tmp
  7z e -y /tmp/ffmpeg-master-latest-linux64-gpl.tar.xz
  cd ~/.local/bin
  7z e -y /tmp/ffmpeg-master-latest-linux64-gpl.tar ffmpeg-master-latest-linux64-gpl/bin/*
  chmod -vc a+x ffmpeg
  chmod -vc a+x ffprobe
  chmod -vc a+x ffplay
  ffmpeg -version
fi

to add ~/.local/bin to PATH, you have to create this folder and relogin.
check file ~/.profile for this lines:
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi


Thanks! Is there any way to add ffmpeg to path? the script didn't seem to do it...

File ~/.profile has adding to path. Create folder $HOME/.local/bin and relogin

Sweet, this worked! Thanks :)
